# Carousel not working in Vue js but working in simple php file

Tags: vue.js, carousel

I am using owl.carousel in my vue app. But carousel is not showing up on the page. I have include (owl.carousel.min.css) and other relevant files(jquery,bootstrap) inside my index.html. These files can also be seen in network tab of the browser which mean files are loading but no carousel(or images) are seen.When I remove owl.carousel.min.css from index, it displays images used inside carousel on top of one another but no carousel. Any idea what the issue might be..??Thank you.

```
       <div class="banner-slider">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="carousel-wrap">
                    <div id="sync2" class="navigation-thumbs owl- 
                       carousel">
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="./images/bslide4.png">
                            <div class="details">
                                <p>Alex</p>
                                <small>Guitarist</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="./images/bslide1.png">
                            <div class="details">
                                <p>MIRA</p>
                                <small>Filmmaking</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And

```
    var sync1 = $(".slider");
    var sync2 = $(".navigation-thumbs");

    var thumbnailItemClass = '.owl-item';
    var slides = sync1.owlCarousel({
    video:true,
    startPosition: 3,
    items:1,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayHoverPause:false,
    nav: false,
    dots: true,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1,
            loop:true
        },
        600: {
            items: 1,
            loop:true
        },
        1000: {
            items: 1,
            loop:true
        }
    }
  }).on('changed.owl.carousel', syncPosition);
```

Comment: And when I try to import owl.carousel.min.css file inside my component instead of adding it into the index.html file. It gives an error saying: "This relative module was not found:

* ./css1/owl.video.play.png in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-41caf81a","scoped":true,"hasInlineConfig":false}"

Comment: It is not easy to use jQuery with Vue - there are conflicts with the `$` variable.. While this CAN be ok to do - it is not recommended. Using a bundler, like webpack, only makes this harder to accomplish. Not to mention, you can accomplish anything you need to do with jQuery using Vue.. Using jQuery with Vue is kind of like importing jQuery (in a project w/o Vue) and just using Vanilla JS for everything - it's redundant and doesnt make sense.  [Why not use a carousel that was built specifically for Vue?](https://ssense.github.io/vue-carousel/examples/)